# unable to get date picker on clone rows in the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I was trying to get date picker on clone rows in the table.But it is not happening

my table code as follows:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control dp4 dob4" autocomplete="off"  name="date[]" required>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton" value="Add" />
```

and javascript for clone row as follows:

```
 $(function() {
                $("#table-data").on('click', 'input.addButton', function() {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
                    var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length - 1];
                    var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
                    $clone.find('td').each(function() {
                        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
                        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
                        if (id) {
                            var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
                            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
                            el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
                            el.attr('name', prefix + (+i + 1));
                        }
                    });
                    $clone.find('input:text').val('');
                    $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
                });

                $("#table-data").on('change', 'select', function() {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val(val);
                });
            });
```

and my date picker code as follows:

```
$('.dob4').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                    startDate: '-0m',
                    autoclose: true

                });
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: did you added the class .dob with cloned row

Comment: Yes i added.but it is not working

Comment: please share your code

Comment: post your complete html dom including `table-data`

Comment: It will be good to reinitialize `datepicker` on newly formed row instead of utilizing the previously initialized one

Comment: where should i share my code ?

Comment: even i tried that as well reinitialize [datepicker ] but it is not working i..i m not getting where is the mistake. vijayP

Comment: Please check this link:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry wrong link ..never mind..

Comment: check the correct link demo:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eax7mk7h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is workaround to it,

**How it Works:**

- Need to remove the class `hasDatepicker`from the cloned elements,because this is what is preventing the `datepicker` from getting attached to the specific element.
- Need to remove the `id` attribute from each of the cloned elements else `.datepicker()` will assume that `datepicker` is added to this element.
- After that call `.datepicker()` on cloned element.

**JS Code:**

```
 $("#table-data").on('click', 'input.addButton', function () {
     ...
    $clone.find('.dob4').removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
    $clone.find('.dob4').datepicker({
         format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
         startDate: '-0m',
         autoclose: true
     });
   ...
 });
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/su3m35zg/18/)

Comment: yes i checked in the fiddle which one shared by you ..it is not working can you please  check once

Comment: small problem again ..its working but the thing it disturbing others input type if i clone a row its applying for others also..

Comment: sorry .still its not working..i just replaced with this glitch and tested .but not working

Comment: i guess u did not get what i m telling actually..if you clone a row [datepicker] should come only for input where we are defining class name as dob4 but its coming for the other one ...hope u understand now...